# Add parenthesis () around counter, remove period from Example

Tags: amsthm, parentheses

I have a hard time formatting my text in Latex. I am trying to add parenthesis to my counters.
This should be a working example:

```
\documentclass[paper]{paper}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[nobreak=true]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\mdfsetup{
  linewidth=1.5bp,
  innerleftmargin=10bp,
  innerrightmargin=10bp,
  innertopmargin=10bp,
  innerbottommargin=10bp,
}


\newtheorem{defsatzusw}{}[section]


\mdtheorem{definition}[defsatzusw]{Definition}
\mdtheorem{satz}[defsatzusw]{Satz}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{beispiel}[defsatzusw]{Beispiel}


\newtheorem{beweis}{Beweis:}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{beweis}[1][\proofname]{\par
\pushQED{\qed}%
\normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
\trivlist
\item\relax
{\bfseries
#1\@addpunct{:}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{erstes Kapitel}
\begin{definition}
   definition
\end{definition}
\begin{satz}
   satzisatz
\end{satz}
\begin{beweis}
   beweisiweis
\end{beweis}
\begin{beispiel}
   beispieli!
\end{beispiel}
\end{document}
```

The changes I want are: 1.1 should be (1.1), 1.2 should be (1.2) and finally 1.3. should be (1.3)

I hope the formating and the given example are okay for you to understand my problem. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Does `\renewcommand*{\thedefsatzusw}{(\thesection.\arabic{defsatzusw})}` help?

Comment: It helps a lot! Near perfect solution. Only   
    `\begin{beispiel}
       beispieli!
    \end{beispiel}`
does not work as intended. It now produces (1.3). instead of (1.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\renewcommand*{\thesatz}{(\thesection.\arabic{satz})}
```

gives you the counter format you want and with a new theorem style (see below) you can get rid of the period after the number in the examples.

```
\documentclass[paper]{paper}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[nobreak=true]{mdframed}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\mdfsetup{
  linewidth=1.5bp,
  innerleftmargin=10bp,
  innerrightmargin=10bp,
  innertopmargin=10bp,
  innerbottommargin=10bp,
}

\newcounter{defsatzusw}
\counterwithin{defsatzusw}{section}
% Since you don't seem to use the defsatzusw environment
% it seems excessive to define it when you only want its counter.
% If the two lines above do not work as intended
% you are using a LaTeX format older than April 2018,
% in that case you can either try to load chngcntr with \usepackage{chngcntr}
% or go back to \newtheorem{defsatzusw}{}[section]
\renewcommand*{\thedefsatzusw}{(\thesection.\arabic{defsatzusw})}

\mdtheorem{satz}[defsatzusw]{Satz}
\mdtheorem{definition}[defsatzusw]{Definition}

\newtheoremstyle{definitionwoperiod}
  {}{}
  {}{}
  {\bfseries}{}{ }
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ #3}}
\theoremstyle{definitionwoperiod}
\newtheorem{beispiel}[defsatzusw]{Beispiel}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{beweis}[1][\proofname]{%
   \par
   \pushQED{\qed}%
   \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
   \trivlist
   \item\relax
     {\bfseries
      #1\@addpunct{:}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces}
  {\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{erstes Kapitel}
\begin{definition}
   definition
\end{definition}
\begin{satz}
   satzisatz
\end{satz}
\begin{beweis}
   beweisiweis
\end{beweis}
\begin{beispiel}
   beispieli!
\end{beispiel}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Everything works fine! (Needed to import the package chngcntr as you mentioned.) This is my first time posting here, is there any way to mark your answer as 'perfect' answer?

Comment: @Flöckchen Great, glad to be of service. You can accept the answer using the green checkmark (maybe you have to wait a few minutes before you can do that? - not sure) see https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers